# How to set variables dynamically using Entity Framework 5 & Linq

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

How would I set the latitude & longitude of the "sourcePoint" dynamically?

I can query database to get the info I need (the latitude & longitude) but I am not sure how to set the sourcePoint dynamically using those values.

This is my first shot at C#, MVC 4, Entity Framework 5 & Linq so I would appreciate some help on this one. Thanks for your help in advance :)

```
        public ActionResult Index(string location = "melbourne-vic-3000")
    {

        ////get the latitude & longitude of the current location
        //var latlong =
        //    (from u in db.Locations
        //     where u.Url.Equals(location)
        //     select u).Take(1);

        //set the latitude & longitude of the sourcePoint
        var sourcePoint = GeoUtils.CreatePoint(-37.815206, 144.963937); //***NEED TO GET THE LATITUDE & LONITUDE FROM THE DATABASE (see query above)***

        //work out the distance each business is from the sourcePoint
        var model =
            from x in db.Businesses
            from y in db.Locations
            where location == y.Url
            select new BusinessDistance
                    {
                        BusinessName = x.BusinessName,
                        Address = x.Address,
                        Distance = Math.Round((x.GeoLocation.Distance(sourcePoint).Value / 1000), 2)
                    };

        return View(model.ToList());

    }
```

---

### ---- working code ----

```
    public ActionResult Index(string location = null)
    {

        var sourcePoint = GeoUtils.CreatePoint(-37.815206, 144.963937); //Set the default latitude & longitude to Melbourne

        //get the latitude & longitude of the current location from the database
        var latlong =
            (from u in db.Locations
             where u.Url.Equals(location)
             select u).FirstOrDefault();

        if (latlong != null)
        {
            //dynamically set the latitude & longitude of the sourcePoint using the latitude & longitude we got from the database
            sourcePoint = GeoUtils.CreatePoint((float)Convert.ToDouble(latlong.Latitude), (float)Convert.ToDouble(latlong.Longitude));
        }

        //work out the distance each business is from the sourcePoint
        var model =
            from x in db.Businesses
            from y in db.Locations
            where location == y.Url
            select new BusinessDistance
                    {
                        LocationSuburb = y.Suburb,
                        BusinessName = x.BusinessName,
                        Address = x.Address,
                        Distance = Math.Round((x.GeoLocation.Distance(sourcePoint).Value / 1000), 2)
                    };

        if (model != null)
        {
            return View(model.ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            //display the error page
            return View(); //TO DO...

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//get the latitude & longitude of the current location
    var latlong =
        (from u in db.Locations
         where u.Url.Equals(location)
         select u).FirstOrDefault();

    // declarre sourcePoint here
    if(latlong != null)
    {
       //set the latitude & longitude of the sourcePoint
       sourcePoint = GeoUtils.CreatePoint(latlong.Latitude, latlong.Longitude);
    }
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion (+ converted to lat long to doubles) but get this error "The name 'sourcePoint' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: @MWD Move `sourcePoint` declaration outside `if` block.

Comment: Thanks @Hamlet Hakobyan.. With your help I was able to work it out.. I have updated my question with the working code if anyone else is interested :)